# win 7 home premium - run batch script on logoff / shutdown

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

is there a way to run a batch script on logoff or shutdown in windows 7 home premium?

[edit] to add a bit of context, im looking to delete everything from my downloads folder when i logoff, so unless someone knows a different way of achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: Sadly, without the group policy editor i don't think there is an easy way to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Task Scheduler? Create a new task, and have at least one of the trigger(s) be "At log on".

Comment: +1 for Task Scheduler. You can set permissions and even have it run as Admin for those UAC enabled machines.

Comment: the OP wants to run a script on logoff though, not logon.

Comment: To add a bit of context, im wanting to delete everything out of my downloads folder when i logoff.

Comment: In that case, why not just install Sandboxie and sandbox the downloads folder, then set it to clear on log off (99% sure thats an  option)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the type of solution you are looking for, but you can just use the batch script itself to shutdown or log off using the <kbd>shutdown</kbd> command.

> C:\ `>`help shutdown
>   Usage: shutdown [/i | /l | /s | /r | /g | /a | /p | /h | /e] [/f]
>       [/m \computer][/t xxx][/d [p|u:]xx:yy [/c "comment"]]
>
> ```
> ..snip..
> /l         Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options.
> /s         Shutdown the computer.
> ..snip..
> ```

Just put this command at the end of your script, maybe with a timer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a program  such as acronis backup on your PC, you could schedule it to backup on shutdown, and include your bat file in the pre or post process option. I used this method to alter the contents of text file on a remote server from ON to OFF.